# Select and Data-Retrieval Operations Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error that says "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations." I know this is occurring when I select @column 2 = cast... But not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

```
   declare 
                column1 int = 0,
                column2 int = 0,
                column3 int = 0,
                column4 int = 0,

    insert into dbo.tableName (column1, column2, column3, column4)
        select @column1,
               @column2 = cast((row_number() over(order by column4)) as int),
               @column3,
               @column4,
        from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value to `@column2` within a table expression. You must do this separately. As an aside, you won't be able to assign `row_number()` and an `OVER` clause to a variable if you don't intend to build dynamic sql with it...

Or, you can just write the `INSERT` operation like this:

```
declare 
    @column1 int,
    @column2 int,
    @column3 int,
    @column4 int

select 
    @column1 = 0,
    @column2 = 0,
    @column3 = 0,
    @column4 = 0

insert into dbo.tableName (column1, column2, column3, column4)
select @column1,
       cast((row_number() over(order by column4)) as int),
       @column3,
       @column4
from databaseName
```

Comment: You cannot declare and assign values to multiple variables in one line. Also you have left the extra commas in Declare and Select statements.

Comment: Whoops - didn't catch that. Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can Declare multiple Variables in One line, Or you can Assign values to multiple Variables in One Line. But you cannot Declare and assign values to multiple variables in One line.

On the other hand you can Declare One variable and Assign value to it in one line. *(Only allowed in sql server 2008 and later editions)*.

Also you left out `@` when declaring variables.

```
 declare @column1 int, @column2 int, @column3 int,@column4 int

 SELECT @column1 = 0, @column2 =0, @column3 = 0, @column4 = 0;

insert into dbo.tableName (column1, column2, column3, column4)
select  @column1
       ,row_number() over (order by column4) --<-- No need to cast as int
       ,@column3
       ,@column4
from table
```

Comment: I need some type of cast statement. Basically, it can't convert BigInt into Int

Comment: Here is the official error message: Data loss might occur when casting from BigInt to Int.